# Is it possible to embed RPMs within another RPM ?

Tags: linux, rpm

Can we embed a set of RPMs within another RPM ?

I have a set of RPMs for several linux variants and architectures. I would like to create a single RPM file using these RPM files so that User would receive and install using a Single RPM file; so that User needn't worry about downloading the correct platform specific RPM files.

Comment: Don't do that. The whole purpose of `*.rpm` files is software packaging. Don't abuse it.

Comment: Hmmm, instead of RPMs, try _self extracting tar files_ which is actually shell script embedded with _tar_ file. Place all _rpms_ into tar file and embed it to shell script and send that script. That script should be made to extract all rpms and install them..  - Simple google gives many article on this

Comment: @Basile, I am trying to create(i.e., package several RPMs) a generic single package using platform specific RPMs. The intention is to encapsulate all specific details and provide a Single RPM file so that it is convenient to share and from Consumer's perspective easier to install with single RPM files without worrying about the platfrom.

Sorry for digging more into this but I want to understand as to why it shouldn't be done this way ? No offense here, I am just trying to understand a bit more...

Comment: @VoidPointer, Thanks for the alternate approach. I would give it a try. However, I would like to know if embedding an RPM is not possible at all ?

Comment: Put your rpm's in a repository, set dependices and install using the package manager (yum/zypper) instead of rpm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not do that.

`RPM`s are single units of software (sometimes split off documentation and debug info into separate packages)

The other way round is usually done by `meta package`s, having dependencies for actual `data/content package`s.

In your case, I would create a `repository package` (a rpm just containing the information about a repository you host). Put a `meta package` plus your actual `data/content package`s into the repository and instruct the user to install the `meta package`, I think that is as hasslefree as it can get, plus all your users get a convenient update path.